# Is it possible to create an MS Access Web App using a pre-existing SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, frontend

We need to building a typical maintenance front end (read, update, create, delete) for an existing relational database, and I have heard that Access Web Apps must "own" the SQL server database it uses.

Is it possible to create an MS Access Web App using a pre-existing SQL Server database?

Sources say the following:

> In the process launching the app to SharePoint, a SQL database is
>   provisioned that will house all the objects and data that the app
>   requires.  The database that is created is specific to your app and by
>   default not shared with other apps.

Comment: What do you mean `Web App`? Like `google mail` or `StackExchange`? Or just be able to access your SQL database over network/internet/intranet?

Comment: Slava, Access Web App. Google it, or go here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Video-Create-an-Access-web-app-10855ec0-3a12-4e6c-a67c-c88267f00a3c

Comment: Wow. Thanks. Will know.

Comment: Accordingly to documentation you can access SQL Server Database. Only the question where that DB has to locate. Azure? Internal network?

Comment: Sure, if you want somebody else to say "yes" :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is "No". Access Web Apps are built on the SharePoint platform and the back end database is stored in an internal version of SQL Server.

Although it cannot be built upon an external SQL Server instance, you can import the schema and data into the internal instance of SQL Server.